# Todays switching technology in Telephone networks

Tags: switch, switching, internet, osi

I am confused with the Circuit switching and Virtual circuit approaches.

In which layers the Circuit switching works ?

In one book there is a line "we will not use destination address in circuit switching" my doubt is that at first time during call setup phase the sender should address the destination to NCC(network control center) if not how it will know?

In todays internet, are we Using the Circuit switching?

can this Circuit switching technology works in store and forward switches?

What is the switching Technology used in todays Telephone networks?

Dedicated path means what? is the whole wire dedicated or the only one channel in the wire is dedicated in circuit switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which layers the Circuit switching works ?

All layers can have a circuit switching, except real layer 1, which has no switching, just a connection circuit.

> ...during call setup phase the sender should address the destination to NCC

Right! in the control plane

> In todays internet, are we Using the Circuit switching?

Yes, in SDH, OTN, connected Ethernet...

> can this Circuit switching technology works in store and forward switches?

There is no relation between CS and store and forward, it'a not a technology, just an operating of the connection matrix.

> What is the switching Technology used in todays Telephone networks?

E1 operates in CS mode.
IP operates in PS mode (packet switching)

> is the whole wire dedicated or the only one channel in the wire is dedicated in circuit switching?

A circuit is a connected channel